# Android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am having two package in my application 
1.com.fsp.deals and 2.com.facebook.android..

i declared my package as package =com.fsp.deals in Manifest file..
 if i want to use the activity in com.facebook.android how i should call activity in manifest file it showing error as i define as

```
</activity> 
     <activity android:name="com.facebook.android.Example"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">           
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use like that, All you activity should be there in the package or its child package that you specify in the Manifest file.

One solution for.
1. Change to package `com.facebook.android` to `com.fsp.deals.android`
2. Then you set in activity in your manifest file like this

```
</activity> 
     <activity android:name=".android.Example"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">           
    </activity>
```

where `package ="com.fsp.deals"`